# CFDs - What are the overnight holding times where you get charged swap fees?

Tags: foreign-exchange, cfd

We get charged overnight swap fees when holding CFD positions overnight.
But what are the overnight trading times? Especially for crypto and shares. Scoured through the internet but could only find the below, which just mentions start time.

[https://www.ig.com/uk/help-and-support/spread-betting-and-cfds/fees-and-charges/why-is-overnight-funding-charged-and-how-is-it-calculated-#:~:text=If%20you%20hold%20a%20short,through%2010pm%20(UK%20time)](https://www.ig.com/uk/help-and-support/spread-betting-and-cfds/fees-and-charges/why-is-overnight-funding-charged-and-how-is-it-calculated-#:%7E:text=If%20you%20hold%20a%20short,through%2010pm%20(UK%20time)): "If you hold a short-term trade and want to keep it open overnight, you'll be charged a daily interest fee. This charge will be applied to Daily Funded Bets (DFBs) as well as cash CFD positions held through 10pm (UK time)."

So, we get charged if we hold after 10pm. So overnight times are between 10PM and midnight? If 10pm is the start time for overnight window, whats the end time?

Especially interested in crypto CFDs and stocks CFDs.

thx

Comment: I don't think it's a range. If the position is open at 10pm you get charged the fee, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Asked the support of various firms. With some, overnight period starts at 22:00 with other it starts at 23:59 and ends after just one min at midnight. Overnight Times vary between asset classes, brokers and platforms. Timezone also varies depending on broker and platform.